# how to compare array for single result using if statement

Tags: php, arrays, validation

i was doing validation for user form after each validation i used to store "valid" in a array index and at last comparing them like this:

```
 if(isset($fullname)){
    if ($valid["name"]=="valid"&&$valid["username"]=="valid"&&$valid["password"]=="valid"&&$valid["email"]=="valid") {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["reg_name"] = $fullname1;
            $_SESSION["reg_username"] = $username1;
            $_SESSION["reg_email"] = $email1;
            $_SESSION["reg_password"] = $password1;
            $_SESSION["reg_gender"] = $_REQUEST['gender'];
            header("location:validation&insertion.php");
    }
```

Well i will check validation and then make session .

**My question is there any short way to check the whole array across a single value like "valid"?**
I hope you have understand my question.Comment it if it is not asked well.
Do not rate as negative.Please ignore my grammar mistakes.I hate those who edit my question's grammar.

Comment: What would be the value otherwise if it is not valid?

Comment: it's value will be not valid i am storing by using if else if regex matches then set value to "valid" else set to "notvalid"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just *count* the number of **unique** values and check if it's equal to 1, then check one value if it is `"valid"`.

```
if (count(array_unique($valid)) === 1 && $valid["name"] === "valid") {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["reg_name"] = $fullname1;
    $_SESSION["reg_username"] = $username1;
    $_SESSION["reg_email"] = $email1;
    $_SESSION["reg_password"] = $password1;
    $_SESSION["reg_gender"] = $_REQUEST['gender'];
    header("location:validation&insertion.php");
}
```

Or just simply check if a `"notvalid"` value is found in the array:

```
if (!in_array("notvalid", $valid)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["reg_name"] = $fullname1;
    $_SESSION["reg_username"] = $username1;
    $_SESSION["reg_email"] = $email1;
    $_SESSION["reg_password"] = $password1;
    $_SESSION["reg_gender"] = $_REQUEST['gender'];
    header("location:validation&insertion.php");
}
```

Comment: @AwaisAhmad I have edited my answer; had some little mistakes.

Comment: i think you should delete first part second part is short and it has work perfectly

Comment: @AwaisAhmad The first part is an alternative though, if you will have another value assigned other than `"notvalid"`. Anyways, no problem.